# how to store view model value to session

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4

i already try to store my viewmodel to session.
**i store my database to viewmodel, and i want to save viewmodel value to session**

i try to use

```
List<GetUserNameViewModel> getName = _accountService.GetLoginName(UserID)
                Session["GetName"] = getName;
```

but value is

```
System.Collections.Generic.List`1[XNet.Repository.Model.GetUserNameViewModel], not Username...
```

how can i save my viewmodel value to session??

this my service

```
public List<GetUserNameViewModel> GetLoginName(int UserID)
        {
            List<User> user = (from d in _UserRepository.All()
                               where d.UserID == UserID
                               select d).ToList();

            List<GetUserNameViewModel> GetName = new List<GetUserNameViewModel>();

            foreach (User users in user)
            {
                GetName.Add(new GetUserNameViewModel
                    {
                        UserName = users.UserName
                    });
            }
            return GetName;
        }
```

my controller

```
   public ActionResult Index()
        {
            int UserID = Convert.ToInt32(User.Identity.Name);
            List<GetUserNameViewModel> getName = _accountService.GetLoginName(UserID);
                Session["GetName"] = getName;
            return View();
        }
```

Comment: i want to get value of Username in GetUserNameViewModel

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the View (Razor), you've to cast the object in order to traverse the `List<T>` if that list has two or more `GetUserNameViewModel` object references or just call `FirstOrDefault()` method to read the first or default element from the `List<T>`,

```
@{
  List<GetUserNameViewModel> getNames =  Session["GetName"] as List<GetUserNameViewModel>;

  for(var name in getNames){
     //statements
  }

 //Or
 GetUserNameViewModel name = getNames.FirstOrDefault();

}
```

And in other case, change the `GetLoginName` method. I think `GetLoginName` method should returns an object not a `List<T>`.

```
public GetUserNameViewModel GetLoginName(int UserID)
 {
   User user = (from d in _UserRepository.All()
                     where d.UserID == UserID
                     select d).FirstOrDefault();

  if(user==null)
      return null;

  return new GetUserNameViewModel() { UserName = user.UserName };
 }
```